# Install nokogiri by copying from one machine to another

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I use nokogiri as the html parser for my website. When I tried to put this website on a shared hosting service I found that I can't install nokogiri because they don't allow access to gcc and so nokogiri can't build native extensions. Is there a binary distribution of nokogiri which I can copy over to my hosting account? If not can I manually install nokogiri on one machine and then copy it?

If all of these are not an option is there a html parsing gem which doesn't need native extensions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Ruby can only parse XML natively via [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html) and there is no option to "copy" the installation by simply moving a few files around. Parsing HTML is more advanced than XML parsing, because it has to be much more flexible regarding bad markup.

One option could be to use [TidyHTML](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to "tidy" up your HTML and then use REXML to parse it. I haven't tried that option myself, but it seems to work for most people.